Does the weighted Louvain algorithm for maximizing Modularity result in one of the modules containing low weight edges for a fully connected network?
I currently have an implementation of the Louvain Algorithm from the Brain Connectivity Toolbox (BCT) written by Rubinov and Sporns 2010. I was discussing the implementation of it with a professor who brought up the idea that for a fully connected network, the Louvain algorithm can return a set of nodes (a module) that have low weighted edges. In other words, I have forced the algorithm to return modules where at least one of them features nodes that are not strongly connected; defeating the purpose of defining "Modules". Instead, I will have at least one, if not more, modules that is essentially a set of lowly connected nodes that do not have any biological significance.
The reason it defeats the purpose of defining "Modules" that have biological significance is because I am interested in characterizing a feature called "functional networks". The idea is to use characterize modules in a correlation matrix derived from fMRI timecourses for a bunch of brain regions. A classic example would be that we have 51 unique nodes (51 unique brain regions of interest), and some correlation between every pair, resulting in around 1280 unique pairwise correlation values.
Papers such as https://academic.oup.com/cercor/article/29/1/397/5144207#134365771 and https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7286311/ would only use positive correlations and quantify modules from the thresholded matrix. However, it does not make sense to remove negative correaltions since high negative correlations in the fMRI context still means that the two brain regions are "functionally connected". And since I am interested in quantifiyng "functional networks", I am interested in quantifying modules that feature nodes that "connected" to each other, regardless of if its negative or positive. Thus, what I have done is used the magnitude of correlations in the correlation matrix, resulting in a fully connected network.
This ties back to my first paragraph with the discussion I had with a professor, and I was wondering if I could get some thoughts on this, and if there are any suggestions how to work past this. Is the only solution to threshold the correlation matrices such that only high magnitudes remain?
